# Loopback 4: How to query an array of objects

Tags: mysql, loopback4

I have been unable to query objects based on a property in an array of objects.

I am trying to query all orders that have the event with id 7:

```
  const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({where: {events: {elemMatch: {'id': event.id}}}});
```

The above gives me the following error:

```
 ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{\"id\":\"7\"}
```

If i try the following filter, I always get an empty array back:

```
{where: {events: {like: '%id%'}}}
```

What is the correct approach for Loopback 4?

**UPDATE:**

I am using MySQL 8.0.

This is the definition of events in my order model:

```
@property({
  type: 'array',
  itemType: 'object',
  required: false,
})
events: CartItem[] | null;
```

Comment: Could you share your Order Model definition so that we may confirm your column mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Since you are using the [`MySQL`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql) loopback connector to connect to your `MySQL` database, currently this connector treats both `String/JSON` as `VARCHAR`. As such, you could try the following modification to like

```js
{where: {events: {like: '%id:'+7+'%'}}}
```

or

```js
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
    where: {
        events: {
            like: '%id:'+event.id+'%'
        }
    }
});
```

**or using regular expressions**

```js
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
    where: {
        events: {
            regexp: '.*id:'+event.id+'.*'
        }
    }
});
```

```js
const orders = await this.orderRepository.find({
    where: {
        events: {
            regexp: new RegExp(".*id:"+event.id+".*")
        }
    }
});
```

in an attempt to match the `json` pattern `{`**id:7**`,name:'Event 7'}` where in this case the value inside `id` could be `7`.

### Assumptions

Based on your question and the mysql error shown, the following assumptions were made:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table samples(id int primary key auto_increment, events varchar(400));
```

```
insert into samples(events) values 
('[{id:3,name:\"Boscobel\"},{id:4,name:\"Rays\"}]'), 
('[{id:7,name:\"Boscobel 7\"},{id:8,name:\"Rays 8\"}]');
```

---

#### Should Receive Results

**Query #1**

```
select * from samples where events like '%id\:7%';
```

```
| id  | events                                          |
| --- | ----------------------------------------------- |
| 2   | [{id:7,name:"Boscobel 7"},{id:8,name:"Rays 8"}] |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from samples where events like '%id:7%';
```

```
| id  | events                                          |
| --- | ----------------------------------------------- |
| 2   | [{id:7,name:"Boscobel 7"},{id:8,name:"Rays 8"}] |
```

---

#### Should Not Receive Results

**Query #3**

```
select * from samples where events like '%id\:70%';
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #4**

```
select * from samples where events like '%id:200%';
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/61Cn24NXRcdkJBiyrzYg1R/0)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I am still receiving an empty array from the database. 

If I perform the following query:

select * from MyOrders where events like '%id%';

I at least get all the MyOrders back. If I do the same query through Loopback (where: {events: {like: '%id%}}}', I get no results, which is strange. I work with MySQL 8 and the column is of type TEXT

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did a local test using `"loopback-connector-mysql": "^6.0.0",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^4.20.1"` and added another example using regular expression matches. Please let me know if this works

Comment: Thank you! Only the regular expressions seems to work for me. Tried it with "like" after upgrading to 6.0.0, but without success. Glad we got this sorted!